# Pegar variável dinâmica

Tags: javascript, array

Estou fazendo um script para que quando cliente clicar em uma das cores que o produto tem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o produto ao lado troque a foto. Porém, como é um array de fotos preciso que cada id contenha um nome diferente.
Então dentro do laço do produto adiciono a foto o id:

```
id="trocarimg{{$id}}"
```

---

**Problema**

Não consigo fazer que ele pegue esse *id* com o complemento da variável ex: trocarimg1 - trocarimg2 ...
Meu código javascript está da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui onde eu chamo a variável *document.getElementById("trocarimg")* precisaria que no **trocarimg** ao final aparecesse o mesmo código que a variável dentro do array pega.
Se precisarem de mais informações só pedir.
Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou `document.getElementById("trocarimg"+i)`?

Comment: Oi Sam, acho até que já tinha tentado. Ele me retorna o seguinte erro _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null_ sei que deve ser alguma coisa bem pequena mas como não sou muito bom de JS (estou estudando) não consigo ver o problema.

Comment: O for é executado antes ou depois dos elementos? Se for antes, realmente irá dar esse erro que vc citou mesmo.

Comment: Mostra o código que cria/define o elemento com a classe `trocarimg`

Comment: Outra coisa, não use uma função dentro de um laço que não dá certo.

Comment: Para testes eu deixei tudo na mesma página, por exemplo. Tenho todo código html+php acima desse código javascript. Não sei se isso responde tua pergunta. Aqui o código completo [link](https://pastebin.com/rhnUG0cH)

Comment: Olá Matheus, criei um pastebin para isso. [codigo](https://pastebin.com/rhnUG0cH), obrigado pela resposta por enquanto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo errado colocando uma função dentro de um laço `for`. Esse laço me parece ser bem desnecessário, inclusive.

Basta usar a função normal e concatenar o argumento `i` na `id` do elemento:

```
function img(i){
   document.getElementById("trocarimg"+i).src = // resto do código
}
```

Onde o `i` é um número que deverá ser enviado pelo click. Por exemplo:

```
onclick="img(1)"
```

Comment: Oi Sam, eu testei dessa forma, porém eu precisaria do laço para poder buscar dentro do array a posição da foto _ document.getElementById("trocarimg").src = '/images/'+string_array[i]['filename'];_ pelo filename dela. Também tenho o problema de ela só mudar a foto do primeiro _id("trocarimg").

Comment: O valor de `i` já busca a posição na array. Não precisa de laço.

Comment: Correto, estou quase haha. Consegui pegar  index do array no **id="trocarimg{{$i}}"** junto com a função do JS que tu me ensinou ali em cima, o único problema é ainda eu acho no  document.getElementById("trocarimg"**+i**) , dando um console.log ele pega as imagens certas, porém não muda.

Comment: Era pra alterar o `src` do elemento pelo valor achado na array. Por exemplo: `<img id="trocarimg1" src="imagemX">`... ao fazer `document.getElementById("trocarimg"+i).src = "imagemY";`, onde o valor de `i` seria `1`, deveria trocar o `src` da `<img>`.

Comment: Correto Sam, no console.log() ele está fazendo bem isso. Se eu dou um console no  **document.getElementById("trocarimg"+i)** ele me retorna o html certinho inteiro de cada item pra cada cor, se der o console em **document.getElementById("trocarimg"+i).src = '/images/'+ string_array[i]['filename']** ele me retorna o caminho da img certo também, porém tirando o console ele não faz nada haha Estamos quase, vou ficar tentando, quando achar coloco a resposta aqui.

Comment: É estranho mesmo. Deveria trocar a imagem.

Comment: Mas show de bola, essa resposta esta correta. Vou marcar ela e quando acertar aqui mando a resposta como ficou pra mim. Obrigado Sam.

Answer (score 0):

Você esta definindo a img com o id (`sponsive" id="trocarimg{{$id}}">`) e eta tentando recuperar usando a classe `trocarimg`
altera i seu js para isso

`for (i = 0; i < string_array.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('trocarimg'+i).src = // o src
}`

ps. Não conheço o framework que vc está usando mas `$id` de `id="trocarimg{{$id}}">` talvez não seja o index do item no array de fotos.

Em `@foreach($produtos->produtoFotos as $fotos)` talvez seja possível pegar o index do item da interação.

Comment: Correto, ele não pega o index. É bem disso que eu preciso também. Vou estar procurando como pegar o index do array.